# Vue in production breaks app when using v-text in button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a strange bug that I've narrowed down, but unfortunately can't create a minimal reproducible example (forgive me!)

I'm using **Nuxt.js**, **Vuetify**, **Vue.js**

When I run in development mode, the app works.

But when I run in production mode, the following component causes the app to freeze (all buttons become unresponsive).

```html
<v-btn nuxt :to="to" color="primary" large v-text="text" />
```

When I replace `v-text="text"` with `{{ text }}` as an inner node, everything begins to work again.

**Before (broken)**

```html
<v-btn nuxt :to="to" color="primary" large v-text="text" />
```

**After (fixed)**

```html
<v-btn nuxt :to="to" color="primary" large>{{ text }}</v-btn>
```

Does anyone know what would change in Vue production mode, or why `v-text` would be the culprit?

Comment: You may want to review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*.

Comment: What do you have inside of your text variable? Also, I don't see any `v-text` in `v-btn`'s API nowhere: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-text Is it coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @kissu `text` is just a string. `v-text` is a [native vue prop](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-text) to set `innerText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an explanation why it works in development but not production, but that's irrelevant because you shouldn't use `v-text` on components (unless that component specifically works with `v-text`).

`v-text` simply sets the `innerText` DOM property on the root element of the component; these two are functionally equivalent:

```html
<v-btn v-text="text"></v-btn>
<v-btn :inner-text.prop="text"></v-btn>
```

Setting `innerText` will replace all child nodes of the element with a single text node, essentially breaking the component's template.

It's better to set the button content the normal way so the component can slot it in the correct place in the template:

```html
<v-btn>{{ text }}</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks! it took me a few hours to even track this down, so not surprised there's some odd behavior going on due to using v-text. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/6466#issuecomment-1209742483

It looks like since you're using Nuxt with the whole SSR/rehydration thing + the fact that it messes up with the DOM in a forced way probably doesn't help.

Meanwhile, as mentioned in the other answer: you should not really use this directive anyway, stick to the [mustache syntax](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-text).